# Using datepicker to check the age of users over 18 years

Tags: laravel, validation, date

I am working on a Laravel web app which works fine. I am a bit new to it and want to add a functionality whereby Larvel should validate the date entered by the user an make sure it is over 18 years. If not so throw an error to the user on the frontend.. Please assist?

**Frontend part of the form**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('b2c.getplans') }}" id="travel_form"  accept-charset="UTF-8">

        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

 <div class="form-group {{ $errors->has('dob') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
      <input type="date" class="form-input" name="dob" value="{{ old('dob') }}" required>
      <label>Date of Birth *</label>
      <div class="error-label">Field is required!</div>
      <div class="check-label"></div>
        @if ($errors->has('dob'))
            <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('dob') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
    </div>

<button type="submit" style="cursor:pointer;"> Get Plans</button>

  </form>
```

**Controller**

```
 //Post Request of plan entries
    public
    function validatePlanEntries(Request $request)
    {

        $validation = $this->validate($request, [
            'dob' => 'required'
        ]);

}
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post( '/getplans', 'B2CController@validatePlanEntries')->name('b2c.getplans');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `AppServiceProvider` in the `boot()` function put this custom validation.

**AppServiceProvider**

```
public function boot()
{
    Validator::extend('valid_birth_date', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator){

        $date_different = date_diff(new \DateTime($value), new \DateTime())->y;

        return $date_different >= 18;
    });
}
```

**Controller**

```
$validation = $this->validate($request, [
    'dob' => 'required|valid_birth_date'
],[
    'dob.valid_birth_date' => 'your custom message'
]);
```

Comment: ,, Thanks for the help,, I am getting the following error **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Validator' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

in AppServiceProvider.php line 47** when I implement it.. Is it an issue of importing Validator class?  Secondly I am using Lravel version 5.4,, with your solution work ~ thanks...

Comment: I could't mention to put this method in the `boot()` function. was that the issue?

Comment: Okay,, Duly noted, It now works fine,, what If I want to add a custom error message to be displayed to the user upon failing of validation

Comment: Finally It works like a Charm,,, thanks alot Tharaka

Answer (score 0):

You can create your custom validator for the age, maybe this will give you an idea:

`$validation = $this->validate($request, [
  'dob' => [
              'required',
              function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                 $now = Carbon::now();
                 $userDob = Carbon::parse($value);
                 if ($userDob->diffInYears($now) <= 18) {
                     $fail('You are less than 18 years old');
                 }
              },
           ]
]);`

Comment: make sure to include `=` too. because 18 years is valid too.